# LINQ select from join table where the same foreign key has records for two different IDs

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

Ok, so the title is a little bit confusing I guess. Basically I have those 3 tables:

```
Line

id | Name
---------
1  | "A-B"
2  | "A-D"


Stop

id | Name
---------
1  | A
2  | B
3  | C
4  | D

LineStop

Id | LineId | StopId | Order
----------------------------
1  | 1      | 1      | 0
2  | 1      | 2      | 1
3  | 2      | 1      | 0
4  | 2      | 2      | 1
5  | 2      | 3      | 3
4  | 2      | 4      | 4
```

So this is some sort of bus ticketing system which I work on of personal improvement.

As an input I get the departure StopId (Stop.Id) and the arrival StopId (Stop.Id). I want to select all lines that has those two stops in their routes (This would mean that in `LineSop` table for the same `LineId` I'll have records with both the departuring and arrival stops, ultimately I would also like to consider the `Order` column which tells in what order the bus is going through those Stops, because even if the line have the two stops I'm interested in, if they are in reversed order I'm still not interested.

I know that is highly desirable to show what I've done so far but I struggle with the where conditions which seems to be the key factor here. For some reason I decided to join `Line` with `LineStop`:

```
var lines = _context.Lines.Join(
            _context.LineStop,
            line => line.Id,
            lineStop => lineStop.LineId,
            (line, lineStop) => lineStop)
```

But then.. I need to check if for the same `LineId` I have records in `LineStop` table with the start and end `StopId` and ultimately when I found such records the the starting `StopId` Order i less than the end `StopId` Order.

Comment: How about joining the `LineStops` with `Lines` first and then join the result with `Stops` like:`_context.LineStop.Join(_context.Lines,ls=>ls.LineId,line => line.Where(w=>w.Id = LineId),(ls,line)=>new {Id = ls.Id,LineId=line.LineId,LineName=line.Name,StopId=ls.StopId,Order=ls.Order}).Join(_context.Stops,lsl=>lsl.StopId,st=>st.Where(w=>w.Id==lsl.StopId),(lsl,st)=>new{lsl.Id,LineId=lsl.LineId,LineName=lsl.Name,StopId=st.Id,StopName=st.Name,Order=lsl.Order}).ToList()` now with the list you can put a `Where(w=>w.StopId == <Id1> || w.StopId == <Id2>)` and get the result.

Comment: @vikscool This `line => line.Where(w => w.Id = LineId)` seems to be incorrect `Line does not contains definition for Where` which seems reasonable since it's not `IEnumerable`. Maybe there is still way to implement this logic, not sure though.

Comment: yes you are correct that was a mistake here is the update query `_context.LineStop.Join(_context.Lines,ls=>ls.LineId,line => line.Id,(ls,line)=>new {Id = ls.Id,LineId=line.LineId,LineName=line.Name,StopId=ls.StopId,Order=ls.Order}).Join(_context.Stops,lsl=>lsl.StopId,st=>stId,(lsl,st)=>new{lsl.Id,LineId=lsl.LineId,LineName=lsl.Name,StopId=st.Id,StopName=st.Name,Order=lsl.Order}).ToList()` without `Where` clause.

Comment: @vikscool Mmm, this is not very close to the expected result. I get the data but there is no filtering neither on stopId's nor Order (this was bonus of course). I can do the filtering in memory, but that's not advisable.

Comment: Sorry as i was not clear on the query, the  `ToList()` is just for the displaying the result you can always put the above statement into a variable let's say `var query = <the above statement(without ToList())>` then later you can do the filtering and ordering like `query.Where(w=>w.StopId ==<id1> || w.stopId==<id2>).OrderBy(ob=>ob.stopId)` and then you can either add a `Select()` clause in it or simply can do a `ToList()` after the Order by condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this can help you out:

First I get the trip from the traveler: "I want go from Stop: 2 to Stop:4".
Once I know the line that has both stops I build the stops and its order.

```
var lines = new List<Line>() 
{ 
    new Line() { Id = 1, Name = "A-B" },
    new Line() { Id = 2, Name = "A-D" }
}; 

var stops = new List<Stop>() {
    new Stop() { Id = 1, Name = "A" },
    new Stop() { Id = 2, Name = "B" },
    new Stop() { Id = 3, Name = "C" },
    new Stop() { Id = 4, Name = "D" }
};

var lineStops = new List<LineStop>() 
{
    new LineStop() { Id = 1, LineId = 1, StopId = 1, Order = 0 },
    new LineStop() { Id = 2, LineId = 1, StopId = 2, Order = 1 },
    new LineStop() { Id = 3, LineId = 2, StopId = 1, Order = 0 },
    new LineStop() { Id = 4, LineId = 2, StopId = 2, Order = 1 },
    new LineStop() { Id = 5, LineId = 2, StopId = 3, Order = 3 },
    new LineStop() { Id = 4, LineId = 2, StopId = 4, Order = 4 },
};  

var result =  (from trip in (from l  in lines
              join d in lineStops on l.Id equals d.LineId
              join a in lineStops on l.Id equals a.LineId
              where d.StopId == 2 && a.StopId == 4
              select new { d.LineId })
              join l in lines on trip.LineId equals l.Id
              join ls in lineStops on l.Id equals ls.LineId
              select new { l.Name, ls.StopId, ls.Order }).OrderBy(x => x.Order);
```

**Expected result**

```
Name StopId Order
A-D       1    0
A-D       2    1
A-D       3    3
A-D       4    4
```

Comment: Thanks. I try to be consistent in using Linq2Entities but gonna try your proposal when I got back to my PC.